# ZSH DELETE keybinding

Tags: keyboard, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using `zsh` and i m  having a hard time with the keybindings for the `DELETE`button. So for example  i would like to use a  command from my `.zsh_history`. To do so i hit the up button. If i now want to modify the command sightly i jump to the first position and hit the `DELETE`key.
But instead of deleting the first char it turn the first three characters to upper case, like:

```
vim .zsh.rc
-
VIM .zsh.rc
    -
```

(the dash should represent the cursor position)
Special characters are not affected by this.

I tried to add `bindkey "e[3~" delete-char` and `[[ -n ${key[Delete]} ]] && bindkey "${key[Delete]}" delete-char`
to my `zsh.rc` but the `DELETE` key is not really impressed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second I posted it, I saw my mistake - I forgot a backslash.

So I changed:

```
bindkey "e[3~" delete-char
```

to:

```
bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char
```

and it worked.